# g++ - how do I disable implicit conversion from 0 to pointer types?

Tags: c++, g++

Specifically, I want the following code to fail:

```
void a(void*){}
int main(){
    a(0); // FAIL
    a(NULL); // FAIL
    a(nullptr); // success
}
```

And I want the following code to compile:

```
void a(int){}
void a(void*){}
int main(){
    a(0); // calls first a
    a(NULL); // calls first a; that's why I have -Werror
    a(nullptr); // calls second a
}
```

The following code does not compile currently, but should according to my rule:

```
void a(std::size_t){}
void a(void*){}
int main(){
    a(0); // two candidates
}
```

Any idea how to make g++ behave like that?

Comment: never tried it but maybe you can make 'a' a class with an 'explicit' constructor and you can override the () operator?

Comment: @Kam operator() also follows normal overload resolution rules. Also that can't be done for member functions.

Comment: Are you ok with spelling it `zero` instead of `0`? That would change a bit what is possible without patching the compiler.

Comment: @Marc Glisse #define zero (0-0) will probably work. But I want 0. I think I'm done with clang (-fno-zero-is-null, have to test). Then I'll go to GCC. I'll probably submit this as an extensions.

Comment: coming to this late in the day but #define zero (int) 0 will also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be perfect, but if you trully want to have overloads with int and pointer, you could use some helper class like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<typename T = void> class ptr {
    T* it;
public:
    ptr(T* it = nullptr): it(it) {}
    ptr(const ptr<T>&) = default;
    ptr& operator = (const ptr<T>&) = default;
    operator T* () { return it; }
    T& operator * () { return *it; }
    T* operator -> () { return it; }
    ptr& operator += (int x) { it += x; return *this; }
    ptr& operator -= (int x) { it -= x; return *this; }
    ptr& operator ++ () { ++it; return *this; }
//  etc...
public:
    template<typename P>
      ptr(P* it): it(it) {}
    template<typename P>
      ptr(ptr<P> it): it((T*)it) {}
};
template<> class ptr<void> {
    void* it;
public:
    ptr(void* it = nullptr): it(it) {}
    ptr(const ptr<void>&) = default;
    ptr& operator = (const ptr<void>&) = default;
    operator void* () { return it; }
public:
    template<typename P>
      ptr(P* it): it(it) {}
    template<typename P>
      ptr(ptr<P> it): it((void*)it) {}
};

void a(std::size_t x) {
    cout << "first: " << x << endl; }
void a(ptr<const int> p) {
    cout << "second: " << (p ? *p : -1) << endl; }
void a(ptr<int> p, ptr<> q) {
    cout << "third: " << (p ? *p : -1) << ", "
        << (q ? "some" : "null") << endl;
    a(p); }
int main(){
    a(0);           // first: 0
    a(NULL);        // first: 0 but warning [-Wconversion-null]
    a(new int(3), nullptr); // third: 3, null + second: 3
}
```

It is not finished (maybe <s>remove that explicit</s>, add more operators, special conversion from nullptr_t, etc), just and idea.

***EDIT:*** Few changes in code, template constructors and conversion to `ptr<const int>` test.

Comment: Before I had reference-counted intrusive pointers but I found out I didn't need them (reference count guaranteed by caller). I wanted it to run faster so I removed them and now the code fails to compile.

Comment: This helper is no overhead. Maybe you should just remove the reference-counting and stay with original code.

Comment: P.S.: You can mark all the methods __attribute__((always_inline)) to be sure there is no overhead.

Comment: Reference counting is sometimes necessary so I'll have to support strong pointers, weak pointers and simply pointers. This will be fun!

Comment: Why not using std::shared_ptr and std::weak_ptr + something like my ptr? (conversion operator and more needed)

Comment: Because cpython doesn't use std::shared_ptr

Comment: Ahh, ok. May the update help you a bit with that simple pointer ;) Good luck :)

Answer (score 5):

You can compile with `-Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant` to get a warning when you use 0 or `NULL` instead of `nullptr`. To promote that to an error, I believe using `-Werror=zero-as-null-pointer-constant` would work.

Unfortunately, this is simply a warning and is not able to change overload resolution rules. I also believe `NULL` must be defined as 0 rather than `nullptr` in order for the warning to catch it, but at least as of GCC 4.9, `std::is_null_pointer<decltype(NULL)>::value` [is `false`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3ba923bd3297e68) and GCC warns when using `NULL`.

Comment: although if you have `-Werror` active it will at least stop it compiling with such things.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `NULL` is either identical to `0` or `nullptr`, I don't think you can force a C++ compiler to behave the way you describe it. I could imagine using [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)'s AST interface to detect the cases exactly the way you describe. I'd expect that typical C++ code will contain a number of intentional uses of `0` and/or `NULL` to mean pointers and/or integers as appropriate.

Comment: I'll add a third example that currently fails to compile but will succeed after the changes I've described. I'm currently trying to do that in clang.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a relatively simple solution to the first problem (it requires C++11):

```
struct must_be_void_ptr{
    must_be_void_ptr(void* p) : p(p) {}
    must_be_void_ptr(int) = delete; // Disallow implicit conversion from 0
    void* p;
    operator void*() { return p; }
};

void a(must_be_void_ptr p){
    void* vp = p;
}

int main(){
    a(nullptr);
    a(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

> [`gsl::not_null`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Ri-nullptr)

From [Guideline Support Library](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#S-gsl). I highly recommend GSL. It's created and backed by many C++ experts, Bjarne Stroustrup himself and Herb Sutter among them. And the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) are actively being integrated into the compiler warnings and static analyzers.